# Created an lwc in a my org. It isn't showing in the integration org when deployed with github/jenkins

Tags: lightning-web-components, flexipages

I feel like I'm missing something. I updated a flexipage with a new template, some new text, and added a new lwc to the right sidebar. Everything works great in my org, however; when deployed the lwc is in the integration org but completely blank. Has someone had this problem?

Here's a shot trying to edit the flexipage in the integration org:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The lwc html file didn't make it to the integration org somehow. Added it directly to the org and problem fixed. Gotta figure out why it didn't get deployed.